# Joining two tables and returning the bigger value of one column

Tags: sql, oracle

Recently I came up with the scenario where I have two tables named emp1 and emp2 and it has following columns and table looks like below

table: emp1

```
dno  sal    
10   1000
20   2000
30   3000
```

table: emp 2

```
dno  sal    
10   4000    
20   5000   
30
```

and the output table is like

```
table: output
dno   sal
10    4000
20    5000
30    3000
```

Comment: do you want to join 2 table with  `dno `, and get  `max(sal )` for each matched?

Comment: actually one of my friend came up with scenario ... but yes we have to join two tables and get a max(sal) for the matched.@NayruLove

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to join the two tables, then use the `greatest()` function to return the bigger of the two values.

As the salary can be `null` you need to take that into account using the `coalesce()` function:

```
select t1.dno, greatest(coalesce(t1.sal,0), coalesce(t2.sal,0)) as sal
from emp1 t1
  join emp2 t2 on t1.dno = t2.dno;
```

SQLFiddle example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/bca1b/1

Answer (score 0):

According to your comment, i think this is what you want:

```
select e1.dno, 
     case when nvl(e1.sal,0) > nvl(e2.sal,0) then nvl(e1.sal,0) else  nvl(e1.sal,0) end as sal
from emp1 e1
inner join emp2 e2
on e1.dno = e2.dno
```

This is for oracle. For mysql, mssql, use isnull() instead of nvl()

Comment: Oracle _uses_ SQL. So "*in both SQL and Oracle*" doesn't make sense.

Answer (score -1):

I think you want to use the results from table2 - but if there is a Null-value in table2 you want to use table1?

```
SELECT table1.dno, NVL(table1.sal, table2.sal) 
FROM table1, table2 
WHERE table1.dno = table2.dno(+)
```

Comment: Please stop using the old, ancient and outdated implicit joins in the `where` clause - **especially** for outer joins. Even Oracle recommends to stop using the proprietary `(+)` operator.

Comment: Thanks friend for your kind reply